# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: TextView must not be null

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to get the the filepath of a file from file manager and display the filepath in a text view. I am able to open the file manager however when i set text i get a  `java.lang.IllegalStateException: textview must not be null`

Here is the code that opens the File manager from a dialog

```
 private fun openCSVUploadDialog(){
        val uploadCsv = Dialog(requireActivity(), R.style.FullScreenDialogStyle)
        uploadCsv.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        uploadCsv.setContentView(R.layout.csv_upload_dialog)
        uploadCsv.window!!.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
        uploadCsv.show()

        uploadCsv.tvUpload.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
                    .setType("*/*")
            startActivityForResult(intent,UPLOAD_FILE_CODE)
        }

        uploadCsv.btnUpload.setOnClickListener {
            uploadCsv.dismiss()
        }
    }
```

Where i am the file path to the set text

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {

        when(requestCode){
            UPLOAD_FILE_CODE -> {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                    val path = data!!.data!!.path
                    csvFilePath.text = path
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

csvFilePath  is my text view

Comment: Have you initialize `csvFilePath`?

Comment: I just referenced the textviews id directly

Comment: Add your `xml` and activity code

Comment: Sorry but how do i do that or what do you exactly mean

Comment: Probably you use wrong id in wrong place which is not related to your current scoped layout.

Comment: Edit your post and add layout and code where you use `csvFilePath`

Comment: Where is this code written?? fragment or activity or some utility class??

If fragment,

Comment: Even if you can put now something in your text view: its not a file path what you see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is this code written?? fragment or activity or some utility class??

If fragment,
initialize the csvFilePath with findViewById in onCreateView

if activity ,
do the same in OnCreate

if some other class, Post the result to activity and update UI